# How to use jmeter 3.2 with jmeter-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using Apache JMeter for performance testing of my web application via com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin.
Since version 3.2 brings up lots of changes, I wondered if I could use this version in jmeter-maven-plugin (this is not part of the Apache JMeter-project).

I tried the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterVersion>3.2</jmeterVersion>
                <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <xms>1024</xms>
                    <xmx>1024</xmx>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                        <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The standard version for jmeter in jmeter-maven-plugin is 3.1.
I found this to specify libraries:
https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Specifying-JMeter-Version

The configuration above did not work for me. I get a NPE (null-pointer-exception).

```
[INFO] >>> jmeter-maven-plugin:2.1.0:jmeter (jmeter-tests) > :configure @ EAdresseBatchImportCapacityTests >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jmeter-maven-plugin:2.1.0:configure (configure) @ EAdresseBatchImportCapacityTests ---
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  Configuring JMeter...
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.136 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-28T13:28:40+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.1.0:configure (configure) on project EAdresseBatchImportCapacityTests: Failure to find org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_monitors:jar:3.2 in http://maven-repository.11.am-gruppe.de:8090/nexus/content/groups/gdis was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

If I use the old library (ApacheJMeter_monitors:jar:3.1) like described in the link above, it does not work (NPE), a newer library does not exist because the monitors-package was removed from project dependency. (as you can see here: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-monitor-test-plan.html)

Do I have to wait for a new version of jmeter-maven-plugin?

Maybe someone of you can help me to figure out how I can make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the 07. May 2017 a new version of jmeter-maven-plugin released. Just use it and you're fine. https://www.artifact-listener.org/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit on 17 may 2017:**

The maven plugin 2.2.0 for JMeter 3.2 has been released with following release notes:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Previous answer before release :

The maven plugin for JMeter 3.2 has not been released yet:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/212

Maybe leave a comment on the issue for author.

To fix this issue, edit your pom.xml and add:

```
 <configuration>
     <jmeterVersion>3.2</jmeterVersion>
     <jmeterArtifacts>

        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_components:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_config:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ftp:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_functions:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_http:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_java:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jdbc:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_jms:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_junit:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_ldap:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mail:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_mongodb:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_native:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_tcp:3.2</jmeterArtifact>
        <jmeterArtifact>org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:3.2</jmeterArtifact> 
                    </jmeterArtifacts>
                </configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue. :)